# how to merge these two .htaccess files?

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to merge these two htaccess files.

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:HOST} http://example.io/

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.io/es/[L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.io/en/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(en|es)/?$ [QSA,NC,L]
```

and this other one

```html
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

any ideas on how to do this? thank you very much

Comment: what is your question? Use a merge tool like beyond compare.. how is this related to StackOverflow, please read the [FAQ].Your question is totally vague and ambiguous, no mention of what programming language, a [MCVE] is not included.

Comment: I want to merge both code snippets toghether and as I dont know .htaccess code i cant manage myself

Comment: Maybe, this will be a starting point on [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) That you need to read up on this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested this? It seems a logical starting point. It should catch your special "not a file" case before moving on to the catch-all you have at the bottom.

```html
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP:HOST} http://example.io/

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^es [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.io/es/[L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^en [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.io/en/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(en|es)/?$ [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: not working sir, when I access example, it does redirect to /en but it does not load the page as if the first snippet isnt working

Comment: Please update your question to include the URLs you are testing with (in example format of course). That will help troubleshoot the issue.